# jQuery - how to change an element based on a selector

Tags: jquery

Firstly, I am new to jQuery, coming from a Java background, so apologies if this question seems a bit weird.

Basically, I have two sepereate unrelated elements on a page, and based on the selector results from one, I need to change the styling on a second element.

I need to check for:

```
$("#slide1.current")
```

Once found, I need to execute the following:

```
$('.asset.assetStyleNone.assetCount1').removeClass('assetStyleNone').addClass('currentSlide');
```

I guess what I ideally need to do is something along the lines of:

```
$("#slide1.current").XXX(function() {
 $('.asset.assetStyleNone.assetCount1').removeClass('assetStyleNone').addClass('currentSlide');

});
```

But my problem is knowing what the 'XXX' should be. I do know that it cannot be a 'click' event, as there are no interactive clicks that change the state of elemenst on this page.

Is this kind of thing possible in jQuery?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: $("#slide.current")  will give you an array of all elements present in document. so you should check the length of that array and do your stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check if `#slide1.current` exists, use this:

```
if($("#slide1.current").length>0) { 
     $('.asset.assetStyleNone.assetCount1').removeClass('assetStyleNone').addClass('currentSlide');
}
```

Note, this check only takes place once, I'm not sure you want a callback on the event your selected element is created.

Comment: Cheers, that's a good start. I guess I do need a callback, as there are a total of three slides (so I have #slide1, #slide2 and #slide3) which are under the control of a seperate pice of jquery and cycle, so I need to add the class'currentSlide' to other elements as the slides cycle.

Comment: And how will users change the slides?

Comment: The slides cycle automatically - under control of a seperate jQuery routine. :)